# Interval for output messages node.js

Tags: node.js

So many messages. How i can do periodical output?

```
ws.on('message', function incoming(message) 
{
    var obj = JSON.parse(message);
    var objj = JSON.parse(obj.data);
    console.log( objj.ui_price);
);
```

Comment: What do you want the output to look like?  Output all accumulated messages only once per every ten minutes?  Output only every tenth message?  Output only messages that meet some criteria?  Combine lots of messages on one line?  Suppress duplicates?

Comment: one line every 1-2 sec

Comment: With all occurrences that have come in the last 2 seconds on that one line?

Comment: no, only one item

Comment: Which item? Just the last one?  So skipping lots of others?

Comment: yeah, just last one

Answer (score 0):

Implement a buffer and periodically print and dump the buffer. For example:

```
var buffer = [];
ws.on('message', function incoming(message) 
{
    var obj = JSON.parse(message);
    var objj = JSON.parse(obj.data);
    buffer.push(objj.ui_price);
    if(buffer.length >= 20) {
        console.log(buffer);
        buffer = [];
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To output the most recent price only once every 2 seconds, you can do this:

```
let recentPrice = -1;
setInterval(function() {
    if (recentPrice !== -1) {
        console.log(recentPrice);
        recentPrice = -1;
    }
}, 2000);

ws.on('message', function incoming(message) {
    let obj = JSON.parse(message);
    let objj = JSON.parse(obj.data);
    recentPrice = objj.ui_price;
});
```

Do you really have JSON embedded in JSON?  Or, can you skip the `JSON.parse(obj.data)` and just refer directly to `obj.data.ui_price`?

Comment: "Or, can you skip the JSON.parse(obj.data) and just refer directly to obj.data.ui.price?"
error, when i use obj.data.ui_price

tnx for answer, i try it =)